# Can I style the map appearance in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet

Is it possible to style the map itself in Leaflet?
For example, by default it's a colorful map but I'd like to make it a light/grey style map for some of our sites.

I've seen some documentation about GeoJSON but that seems to be meant more for the layer above the map, like markers and polygons.

I'd like to be able to include or reference some sort of external stylesheet to change the appearance of the map instead.

Has anyone got some hints or documentation for me on how to accomplish this? Existing style sheet examples for maps would be very much appreciated as well. Maybe something like a gallery of styles or a Github repo.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To clarify: You want to change the appearance of the map (as in the Tiles that display the actual map)? In that case you could either look for a mapset online (Leaflet uses OpenStreetMap as a Default) or create your own. Creating and Hosting your own Tiles is a bit of an involved Process and requires a bit of technical knowledge and some time. I have used "Maperitive" (http://maperitive.net/) for that in the past. There you can define down to the Tee how and what to render on the map using something similar to a stylesheet. Please keep in mind, that you will have to host the tiles yourself.

Comment: I created a custom stylesheet for the map and hosted it on a webserver written in GoLang (Which just serves the tiles as they are on the drive). The tiles are redered on a virtual server which just spends all year rendering Germany - bit by bit. Maperative doesnt handle areas of more than 1 by 1 Degree in WGS84 too well...   Otherwise you could use a commercial provider - put they are usually either paid or limited in their usage. There are some Open Maps as well - maybe one of those fits your purpose. But please be sure to comply with their terms of use.